# ASP.NET Compilation Error HTTP Status Code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http, http-headers

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I have an ASP.NET page written in VB, but I want to code in a custom error message for a "Compilation Error." To do this, I need the HTTP status code that the error returns. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you share you code with us?

Comment: There isn't rally any code needed. I just want to know what error code IIS returns when it detects an ASP.NET "Compilation Error".